# Best Feature selection algorithm Boruta, Step, Information Values(WoE) or RFE

Tags: r, machine-learning, feature-selection, stepwise-regression, importance

I have landing data with 103 columns Would like to understand which algorithm tis best for feature selection and what may be the logic to call any feature as best. 
I have landing data with 103 columns in it.

```
I run below feature selection algorithms and below is the output:

    1) Boruta(given 11 variables as important)
    2) RFE(given 7 variables as important)
    3) Backward Step Selection(5 variables)
    4) Both Step Selection(5 variables)
```

I not able to decide which one to pick up, looking with domain knowledge it appears i must pick up results from Boruta(as it is giving most number of variables and all seems important).

However i don't find any concrete reason to pickup the best combination.

Comment: Why do you use feature selection?

Comment: Hi Tim,To get the most important and contributing features(though did not get context of your question).

Comment: What for? What is your purpose?

Comment: its for loan defaulters. Though after business discussion added a few variables back in the model.

Comment: Saying it differently: Why not just use all variables?

Comment: Yes, could have done it but the model is taking computational power and later would like to derive scorecard based on important features..